# CGContextShowText exception on Mac OS X. fine on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, exception, cgcontext

I have this line of code:

```
CGContextSelectFont(context, "Courier", [storedTextSize floatValue], kCGEncodingFontSpecific);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetTextPosition(context, 0.0f, round([storedTextSize floatValue] / 4.0f));
CGContextShowText(context, [string UTF8String], strlen([string UTF8String]));
```

It produces the same correct results on both iOS and Mac OS. What's puzzling me is that
when I add the general "Exception Breakpoint" it stops the application at the last line (on Mac OS X only) with a "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.2" message. I can click on "Continue program execution" a few times and then the process finishes correctly.

It doesn't stop the app on iOS. If I disable the Exception Breakpoint it runs (seemingly fine).

I don't get this. What's happening here ? Is there an error or not ?

Comment: I assume you properly used CGContextSelectFont to set the proper encoding (Font Encoding I assume since offering up a UTF8string). I had similar issues years ago, could never resolved it, put a bug in and at some point was told to test it that it was fixed. Guess I would not worry about it. Finally, does it happens with arbitrary strings or real UTF-8 ones (ones where the string length is > number of glyphs)? Might be an interesting test.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I've added a bit more of the code for more clarity. I've also tried using [@"HELLO" UTF8String] and it does the exact same thing.

Comment: Did you try the other encoding option, the font one? If you can write a really simple demo app for OSX and show the problem, as well as test on Mt Lion, Apple will eventually fix it.

Comment: yes, I've tried both kCGEncodingFontSpecific and kCGEncodingMacRoman. No change. I guess I just ignore it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an internal error, but it is handled. If no message or error is presented to you, you should just assume the implementation recovered. You should also sanity check your parameters and context. You should not worry about it, unless of course the exception unwinds into your program or a message or error is made to you (since everything is being displayed correctly). You should not try to catch or recover from an exception if it enters your program (from this API). If something did specify that it can throw, and what it would throw, then you might consider handling it -- but that's not the case with CG-interfaces.

Comment: @radvan72 you're welcome. some of the system libraries actually throw regularly -- in most cases, they are handled and do not enter your program. so this really isn't so unusual, depending on the libraries you use.